# yadcf for DataTables: Show only filtered/available values in select dropdown-box

Tags: javascript, datatables, yadcf

Is there a way in yadcf for DataTables, for the values in select2 dropdown-boxes, to adapt to the current filtering of the table.

That means: I want to only see the values in the dropdown-box which are visible in the table right now.

Example:
Go here:
http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source_chosen.html

And see my screenshot:
[image]

After filtering column 1, I'd expect the tag-column to only show "Tag 1", "Tag 2", "Tag 3" because only those are remaining...

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `cumulative_filtering` option of the yadcf

See live demo page https://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/cumulative_filtering.html

> - cumulative_filtering
>   Required:           false
>   Type:               boolean
>   Default value:      false
>   Description:        Change the default behavior of the filters so its options will be populated from the filtered rows (remaining
>   table data after filtering) only, unlike the normal behavior in which the options of the filters are from all the table data